# Cloned Draggable element , duplicates in the same div and while dragging it hides

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Following is the plunkr link. I want to drag the employee name to the any date on the calender.I have cloned the drag element.After dropping ,i again try to drag the events to other cells .Following is the problem  1) Its hiding behind the table 2) It duplicates itself in the same cell if i drop in the same cell as dragging,which i dont need.

```
 $('.div-event-drop').draggable({
        cursor: "pointer",
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid',
        snap:'false',
        stack:'.div-event-drop'
      });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/3W0rljShhd3znb11HccF?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr does not appear to load.